# Vue 3 change event in v-select notwoking

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

i'm using vue3 and i don't know why i cant watch v-select's change

Can someone help. Thanks a lot

I tried

```
//test
Ex 1 :<VSelect
    v-model="test"
    :items="items_status"
    @update:data.status="changeSelecterStatus"
    @input="changeSelecterStatus"
    @change="changeSelecterStatus"
    on-change="changeSelecterStatus"
    v-on:change="changeSelecterStatus"
    v-on:input="changeSelecterStatus"
    v-change="changeSelecterStatus()"
    item-title="state"
    item-value="abbr"
    label="Select"
    persistent-hint
    return-object
    single-line
/>
```

Only v-change works, however it only works when it's `changeSelecterStatus()` and `not working` with `changeSelecterStatus`
owever if i use v-change="eventMethod()" it will give me a bunch of events, because when initializing the component it already loads the data change api, so when i do nothing it already runs x2 the total event of the total data I have. And here I use selecter for multiple columns of data generated by for loop so every time I change any selecter it will give me a series of events with number of executions = total number of selecters on my page

```
Ex 2: <VCol
   v-for="data in datas"
   :key="data.id"
>
<VSelect
    v-model="data.status"
    :items="items_status"
    @update:data.status="changeSelecterStatus"
    @input="changeSelecterStatus"
    @change="changeSelecterStatus"
    on-change="changeSelecterStatus"
    v-on:change="changeSelecterStatus"
    v-on:input="changeSelecterStatus"
    v-change="changeSelecterStatus"
    item-title="state"
    item-value="abbr"
    label="Select"
    persistent-hint
    return-object
    single-line
/>
//same
<v-select v-model="data.status" 
@update:data.status="changeSelecterStatus"
    @input="changeSelecterStatus"
    @change="changeSelecterStatus"
    on-change="changeSelecterStatus"
    v-on:change="changeSelecterStatus"
    v-on:input="changeSelecterStatus"
    v-change="changeSelecterStatus()"
:items="items_status" item-title="state" item-value="abbr" label="Select" return-object single-line>
    <template v-slot:selection="{ item }">
        {{ getTextFromCodeStatus(item) }}
        </template>
    <template #item="{ item, props }">
        <v-list-item v-bind="{ ...props, title: undefined }">
            {{ item.title }}
        </v-list-item>
    </template>
</v-select>

changeSelecterStatus: function(){
    console.log("task");
},

v-change="changeSelecterStatus()" 
-> onload component : return task(data.lenght*2 time)
-> try to choose an option : return task(data.lenght*1 time)
```

Updated :
seems like v-change can work properly if it can determine the correct data based on data.status and key being its data.id, because of the number times the function is run  = number of selectors with v-model="v-model of that selecter"

```
Ex1 -> load component : return 1 tỉme because 'test' specified at default data does not have to be loaded from the api
```

```
Ex2 
-> onload component : return task(data.lenght*2 time)
-> try to choose an option : return task(data.lenght*1 time)
```

Comment: What Vue library do you use for `VSelect/VCol`? It's not clear and there are many select realisations for vue. Please provide more information with links to libraries.

Comment: i'm using the built-in template but it seems to only affect the css, i've also tried v-selecter with the same result, only the text is overflowing when it's too long in the mobile interface

Comment: I updated it a bit because it seems I missed the results of Ex1, which could be misleading

Comment: v-select is not built in, it is an external component, it could be for example https://bootstrap-vue.org/. Built in would be vanilla html <select>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the Vuetify library, we couldn't expect a change event to trigger.

VSelect

```
 component offer @update:modelValue event to listen to options modifications. 


<template>
  <v-app>
   <VCol v-for="data in datas" :key="data.id">
     <VSelect
       chips
       label="Testing"
             v-model="data.status"
      :items="data.items"
      @update:modelValue="onValueChange"
     ></VSelect>
   </VCol>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const datas = ref([{id: 1, status: 1, items:[1,2,3]}, {id:2,  status: 2, items:[1,2,3]}, {id:3,  status: 3, items:[1,2,3]}]);
  
function onValueChange(v) {
  console.log("Value updated ", v)
}
</script>
```

You can find same at below Vuetify playground.

https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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

Comment: it works correctly, i don't know why when i confirmed the suggested answer i cant comment, sorry for the late reply, thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no native `v-change` [Vue Directive](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html)

But it works, since you have

```
@change="changeSelecterStatus"
v-on:change="changeSelecterStatus"
```

Which are doing the same thing: `@` is a shortcut for [`v-on`](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-on), so `@change` = `v-on:change`

The `v-change` and `on-change` have no effect and do nothing.

Replace all this

```
on-change="changeSelecterStatus"
v-on:change="changeSelecterStatus"
v-on:input="changeSelecterStatus"
v-change="changeSelecterStatus()"
```

with

```
  @change="changeSelecterStatus"
```

It is enough to catch the `onChange` event.

Comment: after getting a hint on the answer i noticed the problem is that v-select is not available `@change`. `@update:modelValue="onValueChange"` worked for me